# Trying to show datediff for specific category

Tags: sql

How to show or unshow datediff for specific category?
I currently have

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, DisplayBeginDate, GETDATE()) <= 60
```

and it shows items from all categories.

What should I add if I want it to show all categories except CategoryID 353?

Thanks.

Comment: WHERE CategoryID <> 353

Comment: Thanks but its not working :) I'm not sure if the correct field is CategoryID as it not pulling any data

Comment: Try to provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. DATEDIFF is a product specific function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, DisplayBeginDate, GETDATE()) <= 60 and CategoryID<> 353
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working :) 
I'm not sure if the correct field is CategoryID as it not pulling any data